# SQL Server Spatial Datatypes

Tags: sql-server, spatial, esri, shapefile, manifold

I have exported an ESRI shapefile to SQL Server 2008 using Manifold, which gives me a column "Shape" of type `Geometry`. The Manifold .prj file looks like this

```
GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137,298.257223563]],
PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]]
```

so I assume the SRID is 4326? However when I run this query I expect it to return United States, but I don't get any rows:

```
DECLARE @lat float
DECLARE @long float
DECLARE @g geometry

SET @lat = 40.0
SET @long = -90.0
SET @g = geometry::Point(@lat,@long,4326);

SELECT * FROM Countries WHERE Shape.STContains(@g) = 1;
```

I have tested some other queries which works so I guess the SRID is wrong? If that should be that case, how do I get the correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved: The correct order of arguments is `geometry::Point(long,lat,SRID)`. I though it would be lat,long,SRID ..

Comment: You have to pay special attention to argument ordering in SQL Server. I believe the x,y ordering is different between geometry and geography (or it was during the beta releases).